# Vue2 detect update to data

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am creating a messaging component with Vue2 and Im currently plling every 30 seconds for any new messages and if there are message they will be automaically inserted into the relevant threads, my question is, can I detect when the data changes (e.g. a new message has been added.

The reason I want to do this, is because I want to flash an icon when a new message gets added to a conversation.

Here is the relevant parts of my code:

```
poll_messages(){
    this.get_messages();
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.get_messages();
    }, 30000);
},
get_messages(){
    $.get(base_url + 'api_messages/get_messages/', (data) => {
        this.threads = data;
    });

},
```

So if the threads variable changes I want to know. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

For that is the function of **Vue2** look that reads the properties and runs when you see changes in them

In your solution, it would be something like that

```
 poll_messages(){
this.get_messages();
this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    this.get_messages();
}, 30000);
},
get_messages(){
$.get(base_url + 'api_messages/get_messages/', (data) => {
    this.threads = data;
});

},
watch:{
 threads(){
  // is executed when there are changes to the threads property
 }
}
```

to solve the changes you can validate yourself

```
    poll_messages(){
this.get_messages();
this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    this.get_messages();
}, 30000);
},
get_messages(){
$.get(base_url + 'api_messages/get_messages/', (data) => {
if(this.threads != data){
    this.threads = data;
}
});

},
watch:{
 threads(){
  // is executed when there are changes to the threads property
 }
}
```

Comment: This detects that I make the call and get back data, but even if the data is the same it still fires this function, i only want it to fire if my data is different. Would i need to store the data before the call and after and then compare the 2?

Comment: It only activates when there is a change in the data friend

Comment: At the moment it is firing this everytime i make the ajax call though the data being returned isnt changing

Comment: Try the solution that you add to see

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're component looks something like this:

```
methods: {
  poll_messages() {
      this.get_messages();
      this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.get_messages();
      }, 30000);
    },
    get_messages() {
      $.get(base_url + 'api_messages/get_messages/', (data) => {
        this.threads = data;
      });

    },
}
```

you can add the following:

```
watch: {
    'threads': function() {
    // Do work here when it updates
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Vue update is triggered every time you assign a new value to `threads`, thus `watch` will be run.
Two different approaches comes to my mind to achieve this:

1. If you want to just flash an icon, use `transition-group` to add style changes for item added to your notifications. The effect will remain for specific duration as it is a transition.

Reference: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Transitions

2. Compare it in `watch` and apply changes to new items' properties and then use `v-bind:style` or `v-bind:class` to change their styles:

   ```
    watch: {
       threads(newVal) {
           for (let message of newVal) {
              // compare new and old values and apply changes
           }
       }
    }
   ```

Hope this helps!